# delete sql rows that have same value in other rows

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, rows

I've a table having data as:

```
C1    || C2  
-----------------
a     || 1
b     || 1   
c     || 1   
a     || 0
b     || 0  
c     || 0   
d     || 0
```

I've to delete row 4,5,6. All rows with C2 = 0, that have same C1 and C2 = 1. Suggestions ?

Comment: You should attempt this yourself.. start with some research.. its pretty straight forward.. then come back if you run into problems with your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delete from your_table
where c2 = 0
and c1 in 
(
  select c1
  from your_table
  where c2 in (0,1)
  group by c1
  having count(distinct c2) = 2
)
```